# Hbridge Circuit output

Tags: pwm, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I am trying now to implement Hbridge using 2*p-2*n mosfet "ZXMHC6A07T8
" from zetex semiconductor  , I used the offered spice model and I connected simply as [image: circuit diagram]

and I connected to two PWM

what I do not understand is why the behaviour of the output in in between 9 and 9.6 and look like [image: Hbridge output]

- What should be done to my circuit to get an appropriate behaviour?
- Is it possible to add gate driver for my circuit? if yes how can I decide which gate driver is acting good with my circuit? what is the parameters of choose

  **PIN 6 and 8 are the output**

Comment: What do you mean by "9 and 9.6"?

Comment: The output in the second photo

Comment: http://www.diodes.com/search?type=0&value=gate%20drivers

Comment: Where is the output measured? Can you label the pins on the chip or at least type them out. Add a direct link to the datasheet of the ZXMHC so we don't all have to look it up. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: It's always better to draw out the symbols for the MOSFETs rather than drawing a box with wires going in and out.  It's way more difficult to figure out what's going on and people may move on to the next question rather than put in the effort.

Comment: the link below include the datasheet and spice model offered by the company that I already used there is no Mosfet models offered
http://www.diodes.com/search?type=0&value=ZXMHC6A07T

Comment: @zelf for future reference they do have a schematic editor built into this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinned out incorrectly - the output is on pin 5 and 7.  Data sheet shows pins correctly, but you must count in a counterclockwise direction starting with pin 1: pin 5 is opposite pin 4 and pin 8 is opposite pin 1.  If you connect the pins properly, and you want to run from a logic level, you will need a gate driver or other circuit to level shift the high side P channel FETs.  The gates must go all the way to the rail to turn off the P channel FET.  For this part, almost any gate driver will be adequate.

Comment: http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ZXMHC6A07T8.pdf from datasheet it show that 6 and 8 are the output pins

Comment: One-line answers run the risk of downvotes or deletion. Per laptop2d's response, please answer all of the OP's questions. Add details as to why your answer is the correct solution.

Comment: Data sheet shows pins correctly, but you must count in a counterclockwise direction starting with pin 1: pin 5 is opposite pin 4 and pin 8 is opposite pin 1.

Comment: For a gate driver do you suggest any one? and if I used the 4N version of my circuit http://www.diodes.com/search?type=0&value=ZXMHN6A07T8 can I use the same driver?

Comment: I often use TC4427.  You can't use the part you suggest unless you can get the high side gate voltage higher than the supply voltage to turn it on - you will need a charge pump.  That is the advantage of P/N channel bridges.